# Creating li tags from an array using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm using React without JSX or Redux

Basically I want to create a div, than create list items for the array

```
var arrr = ['foodA', 'foodB', 'FoodC'];
```

And I want to look like

- foodA
- foodB
- foodC

I'm thinking I need to use

```
 var answer = React.createElement("div", null, arrr);
```

then using

```
dom.div.apply(dom, [{}],
slice.call(otherdata),answer);
```

Except I'm not sure how to convert them into a list. div (shown above) is only creating a container div and all the elements in the array are span in the output.  I've tried changing "div" to "li" and the container is "li" with the same results.

Question:
How do I convert the arrr to into a list? I'm thinking I may need to to do nested createElements, or do a foreach loop some how, but I'm not exactly sure.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Bird

Comment: Does this page answer your question? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Not really, because I'm compiling without JSX. So I am unable to used the h tml like stuff inside the JS file.  But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .map() method!

```js
import React from 'react';

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
 render() {
  let arrr = ['foodA', 'foodB', 'FoodC'];

  let answer = arrr.map((food, index) => {
   return React.createElement(
    'li',
    { key: index },
    food
   );
  });

  return React.createElement(
   'ul',
   null,
   answer
  );
 }
};
```

if you did want to use JSX, this would be the code:

```js
import React from 'react';

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
 render(){
    let arrr = ['foodA', 'foodB', 'FoodC'];

  let answer = arrr.map((food, index) => {
    return <li key={ index }>{ food }</li>; 
  });
 
  return (
        <ul>
     { answer }
   </ul>
    );
 }
};
```

If you know JSX syntax, but want to get the ES5 syntax, I recommend using the [Babel online transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctAGxQGc64A5JAdwGFdIA7Jb-JAA8YfACaNk6GADpO4CL35wA3uQCQRbqKRQAFAEpVcOGrXUk8FFGtwAvHADa-TBAiiAgvgA0BF24BC3gQAYq6i7PgAuhTqZhZwKNx0rDp2CdZQ0iAoYLq6fqI-wFpC-nYAfCrkJqZEMACuUNxwADzUwHAA1kgAnrbKcMXagnAAvuUDBWMtAPTt5aRwsaP6FGqxdY3NutXGe6Yt9dTlu6ZqA4nJqaOxarNHJ8amq-o3o6RAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: Thank you will try this out in a few and report back.

Comment: That Babel online transpiler is so neat!

Comment: This doesn't quite work since I am using React 0.12.2 :( but thank you for trying!